# Why a Map (set as Attribute of PageContext in a Tag), is giving error on JSP in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, taglib

I am working with Java 7, Eclipse Luna and WildFly 8.2.1.

In Eclipse I have a Dynamic Web Project with Dynamic Web Module 2.5 and Java 1.7.

I have a class **PageStartTagSupport** which extends `TagSupport`. In there I create a `Map<String, Object>` and set it as an attribute of `PageContext`:

```
package com.srh.tag;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport;

public class PageStartTagSupport extends TagSupport {

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {               
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("NAME", "SRH");

        pageContext.setAttribute("sessionsMap", map);

        return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
    }

    @Override
    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {     
        return EVAL_PAGE;  
    }

}
```

I also have **PageStartTagExtraInfo** class which extends `TagExtraInfo`:

```
package com.srh.tag;

import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagData;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagExtraInfo;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.VariableInfo;

public class PageStartTagExtraInfo extends TagExtraInfo {

    @Override
    public VariableInfo[] getVariableInfo(TagData data) {       
        return new VariableInfo[] {
            new VariableInfo("sessionsMap", "java.util.Map", true, VariableInfo.AT_BEGIN)   
        };      
    }

}
```

In WEB-INF I have a **srhtags.tld** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd ">
 <tlib-version>0.0</tlib-version>
 <short-name>NMTOKEN</short-name>
 <tag>
  <description>Session Tag</description>
  <name>pagestart</name>
  <tag-class>com.srh.tag.PageStartTagSupport</tag-class>
  <tei-class>com.srh.tag.PageStartTagExtraInfo</tei-class>
  <body-content>empty</body-content>
 </tag>
</taglib>
```

Now I create a login.jsp where I access that map and try to add a key and value to it.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/srhtags.tld" prefix="srh"%>
<srh:pagestart/>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%
System.out.println("************* login.jsp: inside");

System.out.println("login.jsp: (original): sessionsMap=" + sessionsMap);
sessionsMap.put("NAME2", "SRH2");
System.out.println("login.jsp: (latest): sessionsMap=" + sessionsMap);

%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But problem is Eclipse is giving me error message on this line:

```
sessionsMap.put("NAME2", "SRH2");
```

And the error message is:

> The method put(capture#5-of ?, capture#6-of ?) in the type
>   Map is not applicable for the arguments
>   (String, String)

Why Eclipse is giving me this error?

Thanks

Comment: "(capture#5-of ?" is actually part of the message? What happens when the VariableInfo has the proper type value?

Comment: Yes "(capture#5-of ?" is part of the message. The error message I put above is the message Eclipse is giving me. I dont understand what do you mean by `VariableInfo` to has the proper type value? I did try `new VariableInfo("sessionsMap", "java.util.Map<String, Object>", true, VariableInfo.AT_BEGIN)` but still the same error.